# How do I override the Points to Pixels iOS specificity and have my image drawn at the right size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, resolution

I have a 64px by 64px redSquare.png file at a 326ppi resolution. I'm drawing it at the top left corner of my View Controller's window as follows:

```
myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redSquare.png"];

myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Given that the iPhone 4S has a screen resolution of 960x640 (326ppi) there should be enough room for 9 more squares to fit next to the first one. However there's only room for 4 more. i.e. the square is drawn larger than what it should given my measurements.

```
// even tried resizing UIImageView in case it was 
// resizing my image to a different size, by adding
// this next line, but no success there either :
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
```

I believe it has to do with the way the device is "translating" *my* pixels. I read about the distinction between **Points Versus Pixels** in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1) but it doesn't mention how one can work around this problem. I know I'm measuring in pixels. Should I be measuring in points? And how could I do that? How exactly am I to resize my image so that it can hold 9 more same-sized squares next to it (i.e. on the same horizontal..)  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an image at full resolution on a Retina display, it needs to have `@2x` appended to the end of its name. In practice, this means you should save the image you're currently using as `redSquare@2x.png` and a version of that image in 32x32 pixels as `redSquare.png`.

Once you have done this, there is no need to change your code. The appropriate image will be displayed depending on the device's capabilities. This will allow your app to render correctly on both Retina and non-Retina devices.